# Import data from CSV to a table in Oracle with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, oracle, csv

I have a doubt.
I would like to know if it is possible to insert data (100K data) that I have in a CSV file, directly to a table in Oracle, using NodeJs.
I have looked for several ways, but I have not found a solution, only the use of external tables but the problem is that I must save the CSV file in a specific directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know NodeJs, sorry.

But, from Oracle's side of story, you could use an **external table** (as you've already mentioned). If that "specific directory" is located on the database server, great! as you'd have to create a *directory* (an Oracle object) which points to that filesystem directory (and grant read and possibly write privileges to user which will be using that directory).

If it isn't located on the server, you'd still be able to do it by using UNC (universal naming convention).

Another option is **SQL*Loader**, a command-line tool which can be used on your local PC (you don't have to have access to and "directory" which is related to the database server in any way). You do have to have SQL*Loader installed, of course. It comes with every Oracle database; if you don't have it installed on that PC, you'd install Oracle Client.

Comment: SQL*Loader is also available in Oracle Instant Client 12.2 or later, see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-instant-client-122-now-has-sqlloader-and-data-pump

Answer (score 0):

There are various Node.js modules to read CSV files.  Use one, and then when you have the data in Node.js, you can use node-oracledb's `executeMany()` to insert multiple rows at once into the DB, see the node-oracledb documentation [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#batchexecution).

However, I would probably go with the earlier solution and use SQL*Loader, see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-instant-client-122-now-has-sqlloader-and-data-pump